# What is the right way to implement move semantics in a class that follows the pimpl design pattern?

Tags: c++

What is the standard way to do it?

Let's have a `class A` that has a data member `std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl`.

For example, should class A's move assignment operator's contents look like this?

```
m_impl = std::move(other.m_impl);
```

Or this?

```
*m_impl = std::move(*other.m_impl);
```

The first case would be much more efficient than the second. But it would raise a few issues.

After moving, the m_impl data member of other is nullptr. Should the moved-from object throw exceptions when it's being used or just let the user run into runtime errors due to dereferencing a nullptr?

For thread-safe classes this would also mean that all m_impl usage needs to be synchronized. I am not sure if calling `std::unique_ptr`'s move constructor/assignment operator is thread-safe or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former. When you are using a `unique_ptr`, you are probably doing it because the object itself probably isn't copyable and/or movable in the first place. So moving the pointee is usually not an option.

> After moving, the m_impl data member of other is nullptr.

That is correct moved-from `std::unique_ptr`. It needs to support destruction and reassignment and everything else is undefined and does not matter what it does (segfault in case of null pointer).

> For thread-safe classes this would also mean that all m_impl usage needs to be synchronized.

Standard library is not thread-safe unless explicitly stated, only reentrant. If you object needs to be thread-safe, you have to ensure it yourself.

That said if a thread moves an object of which it is not a sole owner, it will cause problems for the other threads, because they will still try to access it at the old location.

You could lock the move operations against all operations on the object and define semantics of the operations on the moved-from object to return error in some way, but it sounds like big pain and seriously confusing to use.

Thread-safe objects should really be exception. You should aim for handing objects over between threads so that only one owns the object at any given time and to have all shared data immutable (except possible reference count, which can be done with reasonably performant `std::atomic` or `std::shared_ptr`, which is built on top of it).

If you really need a thread-safe object, it should either not be movable, or should behave like handle referring to it's internals by `std::shared_ptr`, which *is* thread-safe.

Comment: Would you say that if A needs to be thread safe, then it's enough that A::Impl is thread safe? And using/moving from multiple threads simultaneously should just be considered invalid usage? I originally though about making moving the pointer thread-safe and throwing an exception when it's nullptr, but perhaps this is too much.

Comment: @NFRCR: I would either not make anything that should be accessed from multiple threads movable at all, or I would make it behave like a handle, that is use as _shared_ implementation (via `shared_ptr`). But thinking about it more it would also be an option to make the object movable, lock it across a move (yourself, because you have to exclude all operations on it) and report error if the object was moved away (operations on moved away objects are undefined generally, but you can define them for class you are implementing).

Comment: @NFRCR: Thread-safe objects should be rare. Beyond the few cases where you can get away with atomic, thread synchronization is tricky, expensive and limits scalability. You should aim for either handing objects over between the threads with one being sole owner at any given time or making shared data read-only.

Answer (score 3):

A moved-from object is <strike>not supposed to be "alive" anymore (valid but unspecified)</strike> valid but unspecified:

- Destruction allowed
- Re-Assignment allowed
- Other use disallowed

The first option, i.e. moving the *member* (i.e. ones on innards) and not the *referencee*, is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see this with light from a different topic.

How do you swap pimpl class objects?

```
void swap(T& x, T& y) {
   std::swap(x.m_impl, y.m_impl);
}
```

Right?

It only *moves* around the `m_impl` pointer. So, with move semantics, you should also only move the `m_impl` pointer!

```
m_impl = std::move(other.m_impl);
```

However, as an effect, users of your class should not dereference `m_impl` in a moved-from object. This is something move semantics introduces when you use it in your classes. It is up to the *users* of your class to prevent this from happening, just as your code should not do `v[0]` if `v` is a moved-from `std::vector`, etc.